# Sequential Teradata Queries

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a collection of SQL queries that need to run in a specific order using Teradata. How can this be done?

I've considered writing an application in some other language (like Python or C++) to sequentially call each query, but am unsure how to get live data there from Teradata. I also want to keep the queries as separate SQL files (like it is currently).

Goal is to minimize the need for human interaction ie. I want to hit "Run" and let it take care of the rest.

Comment: BTEQ job with lots of `.run file = SQLxxx;`?

Comment: Correct me if I'm mistaken, but I don't think those can be saved as some sort of script that can just be opened/run at a later occasion?

Comment: The main usage of BTEQ is submitting SQL scripts.

Comment: @Hellcat If you’re using *NIX you can wrap the BTEQ script in a shell script for all sorts of wizardry.

Answer (score 0):

BTEQ scripts are your Go-To solution.

Have each query, or at least, logical blocks of several statements, in single bteq script.

Then create a script that will call the the BTEQ with needed settings, i.e. TD logon command and have this script be called in a batch with parameters like this:

```
start /wait C:\Teradata\BTEQ.bat Script_1.txt
start /wait C:\Teradata\BTEQ.bat Script_2.txt
start /wait C:\Teradata\BTEQ.bat Script_3.txt

pause
```

Then you can create several batch files, split in logical blocks and have them executed at will, or scheduled.

Comment: Very interesting! I'll have to try this when the time comes to schedule these scripts for periodic execution. A question, though: In Teradata BTEQwin, I only have the option to save as .bteq (not .bat), would this still work?